# In PhpStorm how to change the colors of Embedded Javascript

Tags: javascript, settings, coffeescript, background-color, phpstorm

Where to change the background color of [Embedded Javascript](http://coffeescript.org/#embedded) in coffeescript files in PhpStorm ?

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the background-color at the following path: File -> Settings -> IDE Settings -> Editor -> Colors & Fonts -> General -> Injected language fragment

Answer (score 1):

We've [added this feature](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-11069) for the next PhpStorm version.